# parallel java libraries

Tags: language-agnostic, concurrency, synchronization, parallel-processing

I'm looking for Java libraries/applications which are parallel and feature objects that can be queried in parallel. That is, there is/are objects in which multiple types of operations can be made from different threads and these will be synchronized.

It would be helpful if someone could ideas of where I could find such applications as well.

EDIT: Actually, language doesn't matter so much, so C++, Python, anything is welcome

Comment: Your question is very vague.  It could apply to just about any multi-threaded application.  What are you really looking for?

Comment: `java.util.concurrent` ?

Comment: Yup, I'm looking for multi-threaded applications. But with lots of shared data. Typically threads try to act to partitioned data structures, I want something where lock clashes are a little more common.

Comment: java.util.concurrent helps in concurrent programming. Something that uses java.util.concurrent is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Is this language-agnostic or java?  You seem to keep changing your mind here...

Comment: language-agnostic. A library like Colt(http://acs.lbl.gov/software/colt/) which has thread-safe data structures is what I'm looking for. Applications are good too. I want applications to study synchronization from a research point of view.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion Actor based concurrency is the best (depending on what you are doing of course)

See this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-03-2009/jw-03-actor-concurrency2.html) for som JVM actor options.

My favourite is [AKKA](http://akkasource.org/)